# Помощь в архитектуре

Tags: java

Я создаю программу для одновременной торговли с разных бирж.

Выгладит примерно таким образом, я создаю потоки, каждый хранит апи ключ и криптобиржу(binance, hitbtc, exmo), после они выполняю метод run():

```
@Override
public void run(){
   while(true){
     if(условие) placeOrder();
     if(условие) cancelOrder();
   }
}
```

И вот когда они выполняю методы placeOrder или cancelOrder реализация сильно меняется взависимости от криптобиржи, выглядит примерно так:

```
synchronized void placeOrder(){
   String link = ""; // это может быть api.hitbtc.com или api.binance.com...
   String method = "POST";
   Url url = new Url(link);
   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   con.setRequestMethod(method);
}
```

И нужно чтобы для каждой биржи ставился правильный url но если использовать if, то их выйдет много и это замедлит программу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не следует вычислять адрес эндпоинта внутри потока. Этот адрес врядли будет меняться, поэтому лучше сделать этот адрес неотъемлемым свойством самого потока на этапе его создания.

**Способ 1:** Сделайте в Вашем классе абстрактный метод, возвращающий урл. Например так:

```java
public abstract class Trader implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...
        placeOrder();
        // ...
    }

    private void placeOrder(){
        String link = getApiEndpoint();
        // ...
    }

    abstract String getApiEndpoint();

}
```

И при заполнении пула тредами, переопределяйте его вот так:

```java
public class Bot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(
                new Trader() {
                    @Override
                    String getApiEndpoint() {
                        return "binance-api";
                    }
                });
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(
                new Trader() {
                    @Override
                    String getApiEndpoint() {
                        return "exmo-api";
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

**Способ 2:** просто передавайте нужное значение через конструктор:

```java
public class Trader implements Runnable{

    String apiEndpoint;
    
    public Trader(String apiEndpoint){
        this.apiEndpoint = apiEndpoint;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...
        placeOrder();
        // ...
    }

    private void placeOrder(){
        // Use apiEndpoint here;
    }

}
```

И затем:

```java
public class Bot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Trader("binance-api"));
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Trader("exmo-api"));
    }

}
```

**P.S.** - В первом случае Вы сможете использовать механизм обратного вызова если потребуется, т.е. обращаться к коду вызывающего потока из вызываемого.

Comment: едпоинтов много, где-то 10-15. Мне кажется тогда наверное надо использовать 2 способ, и в конструкторе определить все ендпоинты, попробую так

Comment: Думаю можно просто написать "запускатор" который будет создавать новый потоки с заданным адресом.

Comment: то-есть хранить все аддреса ендпоинтов в потоке?

Comment: Хранить все адреса эндпоинтов в главном потоке (в мейне - все равно их надо где-то хранить) и при создании нового воркера задавать ему ендпоинт через конструктор.